# default copy move constructor efficiency different

Tags: c++, move-constructor

if **default copy constructor** provider by compiler only make a shallow copy(copy the pointer of a member in heap to target object's corresponding member field), what is the difference between **default copy constructor** and **default move constructor**?

I think default move constructor should not be more more efficient than default copy constructor, as no deep copy happened. Am I right?

Comment: You are correct.  For built in types and pointers a move is a copy.  Moving only is a benefit when you have a object like a `vector` that stores a pointer to some memory.

Comment: Might be some small performance difference leaving the moved-from object in a safe-but-unspecified state, but it'll probably be pretty small.

Comment: A default copy constructor does memberwise copy of the data members while a default move constructor does memberwise move of the data members.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what is the difference between default copy constructor and default move constructor?

A **default copy constructor** does **memberwise copy** of the data members while a **default move constructor** does **memberwise move** of the data members. That is, the default move constructor steal resources instead of copying them from the passed argument.