# Is there a shorthand method to writing move constructors?

Tags: c++, constructor, move

I have a class with one strong pointer and a lot of object members.  Writing copy and move constructors for an object like this involves a lot of tedious copy/pasting, however...

Is there any way to shorten this, without giving up my beautiful naked pointer?  Like if I could perform the default generated move operation, with just one extra instruction to nullify the naked pointer afterwards?

```
class Example {
public:
    Example() 
        : m_multiplexDevice(getDevice(B737M_mpDevice, true))
    {
        engageDevice(m_multiplexDevice);
    }

    Example(Example && other)
        : m_multiplexDevice     (other.m_multiplexDevice    )
        , m_pilotStack          (std::move(other.m_pilotStack       ))
        , m_pasStack            (std::move(other.m_pasStack         ))
        , m_pitchAttackLimits   (std::move(other.m_pitchAttackLimits))
        , m_yawToPitchBalance   (std::move(other.m_yawToPitchBalance))
        , m_engineBalance       (std::move(other.m_engineBalance    ))
    { 
        other.m_multiplexDevice = NULL;
    }

    Example & operator=(Example && other) {
        if (this != &other) {
            // ignore that this is incorrect (not properly destroying in assignment), 
            // working with client code that kinda sucks
            m_multiplexDevice    = other.m_multiplexDevice;
            m_pilotStack         = std::move(other.m_pilotStack         );
            m_pasStack           = std::move(other.m_pasStack           );
            m_pitchAttackLimits  = std::move(other.m_yawToPitchBalance  );
            m_yawToPitchBalance  = std::move(other.m_yawToPitchBalance  );
            m_engineBalance      = std::move(other.m_engineBalance      );
            m_multiplexDevice = NULL;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    Example(const Example & other) =delete;

    Example & operator=(const Example & other) =delete;

    ~Example() {
        if (m_multiplexDevice)
            disengageDevice(m_multiplexDevice);
        delete m_multiplexDevice;
    }

private:
    char STRONG * m_multiplexDevice;
    std::vector<uint32> m_pilotStack;
    std::vector<uint32> m_pasStack;
    std::vector<uint32> m_pitchAttackLimits;
    std::vector<uint32> m_yawToPitchBalance;
    std::vector<uint32> m_engineBalance;
    // ... etc
};
```

Comment: Use the default move/copy constructor? It will do memberwise move and copy? See this: [what does default copy/move constructor do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71492042/12002570)

Comment: The default variant would probably do the right thing, have you tried it? I.e. `Example(Example &&) = default;`

Comment: _"without giving up my beautiful naked pointer"_ you already know the problem.

Comment: Your move assignment operator has a bug, by the way.

Comment: Wouldn't I need to assign NULL to the strong pointer myself, less the moved-from object thinks it owns it when it's dtor is called?

Comment: Oh, you're using a pointer. Why?

Comment: Which is why you __don't__ use raw pointers. "Doctor my head hurts when I bang against the wall", maybe don't do that?

Comment: There's little to no beauty in a raw pointer. Just rewrite this using `std::unique_ptr` with a custom deleter and you don't even have to mention the copy/move constructor/assignment operators, since the defaults are suitable for your scenario (you could still `= default` them to add clairity): `struct DeviceDeleter {  void operator()(char STRONG* device) const { disengageDevice(device); delete device; }};` `std::unique_ptr<char STRONG, DeviceDeleter> m_multiplexDevice;`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - I like how they feel in practice.  Maybe that's a silly reason of course haha.  Also, thank you for catching that!  it's old code from my employer, I probably should've proofed it better.

Comment: Can the code be refactored to use smart pointers (more specifically `std::unique_ptr`)? Then do that, and your movement will be solved. :)

Comment: The standard name is `uint32_t` not `uint32`.

Comment: A sensible design has two kinds of classes. One kind with one data member (or very few tightly coupled data members, such as an object pointer and a control block pointer) and all the copy/move constructors/destructors/assignments, as per [the rule of five](https://cpppatterns.com/patterns/rule-of-five.html). (Only people who need custom RAII management should write those; the rest of us are well served by standard library classes). The other kind has no copy/move constructors/destructors/assignments, as per [the rule of zero](https://cpppatterns.com/patterns/rule-of-zero.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `unique_ptr` with a custom deleter.

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>
#define STRONG /* ??? */
void disengageDevice(char STRONG*);
#define B737M_mpDevice 1
char STRONG *getDevice(int, ...);
void engageDevice(char STRONG *);


class Example {
public:
    Example() 
        : m_multiplexDevice(
            getDevice(B737M_mpDevice, true),
            deconstruct_m_multiplexDevice)
    {
        engageDevice(m_multiplexDevice.get());
    }

    static void deconstruct_m_multiplexDevice(char STRONG *p) {
        if (p) {
            disengageDevice(p);
            delete p;
        }
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<
        char STRONG,
        decltype(&deconstruct_m_multiplexDevice)
    > m_multiplexDevice;
    std::vector<uint32_t> m_pilotStack;
    std::vector<uint32_t> m_pasStack;
    std::vector<uint32_t> m_pitchAttackLimits;
    std::vector<uint32_t> m_yawToPitchBalance;
    std::vector<uint32_t> m_engineBalance;
    // ... etc
};
```